# Personalized web parts summary links

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, hyperlink, summary

I would need to have a personalized summary links web part in a given page. 
So when a user logs into the site, he should see his own links as opposed to system wide links inside the links web part.

Is it possible to have a personalized summary links web part?
How would that work?

Thanks in advance.

W

Comment: That depends on how you want the user to enter the links

Comment: the user clicks the link to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1. Add a *User* column to a standard links list.
2. Create a new view that shows only links of current user (use [[Me] marker](http://sharefort.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-me-filter-in-sharepoint.html) as column value in filter).
3. Modify the Web Part to use the new view.